# Can't get the height of a div element

Tags: jquery, html, css

It's a stupid question but I can't seem to figure it out. Basically I want the height of my div element. But some how it keeps returning 0. When i inspect the element in Chrome it gives me a height. Code:

HTML

```
<div id="signup">
              <div class="panel">
              </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel
{
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #0071bc;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0.3em solid;
  border-color: #073b73;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

}
```

JQuery:

```
alert($("#signup .panel").outerHeight());
alert($("#signup .panel").height());
```

I have used the above lines in the following methods:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});

$(window).load(function(){
});
```

Every time I try to alert the height I just keep getting 0. What I have noticed is that in the CSS if I specify a height, i.e. `height:361px;` or `height:40%;` I get 361 or 40. But I dont want this. My panels height changes based on the elements with in it. I want signin's height once its rendered. I've now tried... I have no idea how to do this. Please help.

Comment: Are you including jQuery?  It's working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/Sryzk/).  Side note: `console.log()` is better than `alert()`.  It's less annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why height returns as "0" with no data:**

This seems right to me. `height()` returns the height without padding and margin. And because the element has no content (*data*) the height is returned as 0.

**Why it works with outerHeight:**

The reason chrome shows a height is because you have padding and borders. Which is why you get a value for `outerheight()`. `OuterHeight()` will return the height with padding and borders. And if you use `outerHeight(true)`you will get the height of the element plus the padding, border, and margin.

**NOTE:**

If you want the height of an element including padding but not the border. You would use `innerHeight()`. and `innerHeight(true)` if you want padding and margin height without border height.

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/):

Comment: Yes. outerHeight() will show the height of an empty div with padding and borders )

Comment: Isn't the OP getting 0 height for both though?  He said the only time he *didn't* get 0 was when he explicitly set a height for the div.

Comment: When I run his code in fiddle I get "40" back as a value for outerHeight. http://jsfiddle.net/YZATJ/1/ Which is because he has defined padding and border.

Comment: I don't doubt that, since your explanation for how each works is correct.  In the question though he said he got 0 every time.  Maybe I just misunderstood.  Nice explanation though!

Answer (score 0):

The code as is works, as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/Sryzk/).  If the code is not functioning, the problem is elsewhere.  Make sure jQuery is linked, and there are no errors in the console.

The fiddle HTML:

```
<div id="signup">
  <div class="panel">
    Tons of Content<br>
    Even More Content
  </div>
</div>
```

The fiddle jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($("#signup .panel").height());
});
```